# Computer dosen't return -1 if I input a number equal to INTMax+1

Tags: c, int, overflow, twos-complement

The type int is 4-byte long and I wrote a little procedure in C under Ubuntu to print the number I've just input. When I input 2147483648, i.e. 2^31, it prints 2147483647 rather than -1. The same thing happens when I input any number larger than 2147483647. Why doesn't it overflow to -1 as I learnt form book but seems like truncated to INT_Max and what happened in the bits level?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int x;
  scanf("%d",&x);
  printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

I made a mistake. INT_Max+1 should equal to INT_Min. I modified the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int x=2147483647;
  int y=x+1;
  printf("%d",y);
}
```

and the output is `-2147483648`
Now I'm just wondering what happened when I call the function scanf? I think it truncated all the input number larger than 2147483647 to 2147483647.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to help, when you're not showing us your code?!

Comment: You might want to add the proper code you used. It's probably related to the input function that truncate your input.

Comment: Sorry for that~ I thought it was too simple to put it on~:P @unwind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation of 2147483647 ie INT_MAX is `0x7FFFFFFF`.
If you add 1, you'll get an **undefined behaviour**.
This said, in practice, if you add 1, you'll get `0x80000000` ie -2147483648.
I don't know why you expect -1 as its binary encoding is `0xFFFFFFFF`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(){
  int val1 = 2147483647;
  int val2 = val1+1;
  int x;

  printf("errno before : %d\n",errno);
  scanf("%d",&x);                        //enter 2147483648 or a larger value
  printf("errno after : %d\n\n",errno);

  printf("val1 = %d (0x%X)\n", val1, val1);
  printf("val2 = %d (0x%X)\n", val2, val2);
  printf("x    = %d (0x%X)\n", x, x);

  return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
errno before : 0
errno after : 34 //0 if the entered value is in the range of 4-bytes integer

val1 = 2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFF)
val2 = -2147483648 (0x80000000)
x    = 2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFF)
```

The reason why you get `x=2147483647` is that `scanf` clamps the value to the possible range.
If you check `errno` after `scanf` call, you will see that it is equal to `ERANGE` (code 34)

Comment: Yes yes ~!! I made a mistake. It's -2147483648, the INT_Min. But why couldn't I get the negative answer using my code?

Comment: I modified my code like yours, it does get -2147483648. What's the difference between using a scanf function to store the number and immediately assigning the number to a variable?

Comment: @twoyoung, `scanf` clamps the value to 2147483647 and sets errno to ERANGE.

Answer (score 3):

By the C99 standard 6.5 Expressions:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or *not in the range of representable* values for its type), the behavior is **undefined**.

See here:

```
int i = 2147483648;
printf("%d",i);
```

http://ideone.com/07THjV

```
void main()
```

By the way `main` returns `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read input in hexadecimal and will get proper output

```
int main(void) {
int a;

printf("\nEnter number :"); scanf("%X",&a);
printf("\n\n%d\n\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```

input value : 80000000
Output will be :-2147483648
**OR you can use like this**

```
printf("\nEnter number :"); scanf("%u",&a);
```

input value : 2147483648
Output will be :-2147483648

Comment: And what if the format specification in scanf is signed like %d?

Comment: And When you input value [with scanf("%d",&a)] greater than INT_MAX, scanf takes INT_MAX due to %d (integer format specifier). But in case of %u the input range will be INT_MAX*2+1 hence you can input value more than INT_MAX .

Comment: Can you explain to me why "scanf takes INT_MAX due to %d when I input value [with scanf("%d",&a)] greater than INT_MAX"? This is the place where I really can't understand.