# why doesn't long long int overflow?

Tags: c, linux, long-integer

```
long long int a;
scanf("%lld",&a);
printf("n : %lld\n",a);
```

input is `9223372036854775808 (LLONG_MAX + 1)`

but output is `9223372036854775807 (LLONG_MAX)`

x64 GNU/Linux and I use GCC compiler

Comment: How exactly did you expect it to "overflow"? It's *undefined behaviour*. Period.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour.  However, one might surmise from the GCC documentation on other [other integer parsing routines](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-of-Integers.html) that they are explicitly clamping integer number ranges.

Comment: Pass it `LLONG_MAX` and afterwards do a `++a` and you will see your (still undefined behaviour) integer overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Overflow in `scanf` triggers undefined behavior.

However, many popular implementations of `scanf` use functions from `strto...` group internally to convert strings into actual numbers. (Or, maybe more precisely, they use the same lower-level implementation primitives as `strto...` functions.) `strto...` functions generate max value of the target type on overflow. The side effect of that implementation is what you observe in your test. `strtoll` was apparently used, which produces `LLONG_MAX` on positive overflow.

But you should not rely on that, since the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Because `scanf` clamps input to valid ranges, but raises the `ERANGE` error, as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491933/computer-dosent-return-1-if-i-input-a-number-equal-to-intmax1) and in [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

> The value **`EOF`** is returned if the end of input is reached before
>   either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.
>   **`EOF`** is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error
>   indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set
>   indicate the error.

...

> **`ERANGE`** The result of an integer conversion would exceed the size that
>     can be stored in the corresponding integer type.

Note this behaviour isn't required by the language or POSIX standards, but is evidently true for many standard library implementations (including yours).

Answer (score 1):

Signed overflow is undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

It is an undefined behavior. In this if you assign that value to variable instead of getting
from input, that time you will get the warning while compilation.

Answer (score 0):

output will be unpredictable.
i have tried the same piece of code with simple int .
i have attached the output . [image]